# How to zoom in on a certain part of an image using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I used a module called face recognition to create an outline of the lips on any photo, and wanted to modify the picture to just see the lips and not the full face. However I don't know how to do this.

I have tried to convert the face_landmarks into a numpy array and then show it, but realized that it just shows the coordinates of the lips.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import face_recognition
import numpy as np

# Load the jpg file into a numpy array
image =
```

face_recognition.load_image_file("/Users/23Athreyad/Documents/trump.jpg")

```
# Find all facial features in all the faces in the image
face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)


for face_landmarks in face_landmarks_list:
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(image)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image, 'RGBA')

    # Gloss the lips
    d.polygon(face_landmarks['top_lip'], fill=(150, 0, 0, 128))
    d.polygon(face_landmarks['bottom_lip'], fill=(150, 0, 0, 128))


   print(face_landmarks['top_lip'])
   pil_image.show()
```

The expected result is a zoomed in picture of the lips, but I am not sure how to get to that.

Comment: I think this answer is exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953525/1469465

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop image with settable center and scale in Python PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832654/crop-image-with-settable-center-and-scale-in-python-pil)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the rectangle delimiting the lip, you can just get the coordinate of the top left of the rectangle (the smallest 'x' and 'y' coordinate) and the bottom right coordinate (the biggest 'x' and 'y' coordinate) and use:

```py
lip = image.crop((min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y))
```

Note that `image` is a `PIL Image` object.